# WebSphere Developer Tools 8.0 Not able to start server in modern Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-8, ibm-wdt, websphere-9

I am trying to run Eclipse WebSphere Developer Tools with a local WebSphere 8.0.x installation. I also installed IBM's WebSphere Dev server and am having trouble successfully starting each server.

This is because the instructions say that the eclipse.ini should be updated to point to the IBM/WAS/AppServer/jre so that they match up. If you do not do this, the server will start but will spin at 100% because Eclipse can't get confirmation it started correctly.  Eclipse warns you about not having the Eclipse JRE match the server JRE version.

I am using Eclipse Oxygen, which is Java 1.8.  I installed WebSphere Developer Tools 8.0.x.  WAS 8 is java 1.6, as such the server JRE/JDK is 1.6.  Why would they make this tool for Eclipse Mars, Neon, Oxygen if you can't ever complete their instructions and make the Eclipse JRE align with the server JRE?  Is there a way to get around this? I am wondering what I missed.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the instructions to which you refer?

Comment: `This is because the instructions say that the eclipse.ini should be updated to point to the IBM/WAS/AppServer/jre so that they match up.` This is wrong, irregardless of the instructions. THey need to point to different JDKs. What eclipse uses, what you compile against, and what websphere uses can be all different.

Comment: Thanks! This is one - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_eclipse.htm#installingfromdownloadedinstallationfiles

Comment: Also https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1208_cheng/1208_cheng.html

Comment: You won't have cacert lined up with the server so you won't have permission to publish if you don't use the same JRE location as the server is using.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Oxygen only supports Java 8 and above.  You can get the JDK 8 from WebSphere Application Server v9 to run WDT in Oxygen.  If you can point me to the instructions that you were following, we can review (and update if needed) to make sure the instructions are clear.

Comment: This is one: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/t_install_wdt_eclipse.htm#installingfromdownloadedinstallationfiles

Comment: Also https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1208_cheng/1208_cheng.html

Comment: Ok so I did that - I installed WAS v9 and then pointed to that JRE to run Eclipse Oxygen.  It resolved the problem in that my WAS 8.0 server now starts up and the app publishes! However, I cannot "republish" to the server. I get the following error:

'The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start.
The failure to perform a republish may be caused by a SSL issue. Follow the "Resolving the problem" section in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21634467.

Comment: After completing the steps, restart the workbench.
Failure uploading archive to server:
Upload retry limit exceeded for file C:\Users\n0171781\workspace-kepler1\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.etools.wrd.websphere.core\tmp1519785573591\update.zip. Exception: java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory:
Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory'

Comment: I followed the steps in the link but it didn't resolve the issue even though it added the WAS8 cert to my JRE's cacert.  I also tried copying the WAS8 JRE's cacert over my WAS 9 JRE's cacert ,and that also did not correct the issue.  I am so close to getting this working, any ideas?